# WPF soft phone control

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, sip

We have a custom built WPF CRM and are looking to integrate a soft phone client so that operators don't have to manually enter phone numbers. From what I can see on the web there are no WPF soft phone clients and it looks like we'll have to build our own from scratch.

Does anyone know of any WPF soft phone implementations out there? I did find [this](http://www.vista-files.org/programs/conaito-technologies/sip-phone-dll.html) library which could help me build it from scratch

Answer (score 0):

I started recently using the conaito library although not in a WPF app. I'm still using Winforms. It seems to be well behaved and it's doing a good job. You can download a fully functional trial version which comes wit a load of example code.